# Chess pairing program for double round robin

Tags: software, swiss-pairing

We have regular friendly matches in our chess club. So far we have used an older version of swiss manager for swiss and round robin; but today when we had to pair using double round robin format, I was so puzzled.

Is there a chess pairing system that can be used for double round robin system?

Comment: Any reason why you couldn't just use the round robin schedule twice, reversing colors the second time?

Comment: I can't print out as a single result. Tie break would be another issue. Would look complicated. I took a sheet of paper, drew a cross table and finished the tournament with manual pairing today. For tie-breaks - Max number of wins and.... blitz games :P

Answer (score 1):

Just use the ["Berger" Pairings/Tables](http://www.tournamentdirector.co.uk/berger_pairings.html). If there are an odd number of players, then a "dummy" player is added. When creating the pairings each round, whoever is playing the "dummy" player is simply receiving a bye. Then you run it again with colors reversed. If your program has no major issues, you should be able to manually enter people into your program, and the program should allow for people to be paired again with reversed colors.